# How create a cart with prisma

Tags: reactjs, node.js, typescript, express, prisma

I'm not able to create a post and get route for products with Prisma.
I'm using reactjs + express + prism with a folder for the front and another for the backend.

I want to create a route for the user's carts. This cart will have items. I want to take the quantity of the item and the price of the product to calculate the total price.

```
model User {
id        String   @id @default(uuid())
name      String   @unique
email     String   @unique
imageUrl  String
carts     Cart[]
createdAt DateTime @default(now())
}

model Product {
id          String     @id @default(uuid())
name        String
description String
imageUrl    String
price       Float
Cart        Cart?      @relation(fields: [cartId], references: [id])
cartId      String?
CartItem    CartItem[]
}

// Modelo de carrinho
model Cart {
id         String     @id @default(uuid())
products   Product[]
user       User       @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
userId     String
totalPrice Float
createdAt  DateTime   @default(now())
CartItem   CartItem[]
}

model CartItem {
id        String  @id @default(uuid())
cart      Cart    @relation(fields: [cartId], references: [id])
cartId    String
product   Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
productId String
quantity  Int
}
```

Can you guide me, I can't get help on the web ?

I tried to create the post route with it is very difficult to manipulate the related tables